# Spacing the answers

Tags: matlab

How can I change the spacing in my answers?

Let' say I have 2 vectors which I substitute with symbols so my answers are:

V1 = 'hi' 'my' 'bye' 'hi' 'why'(etc. and the 2nd row is)

V2 = 'h->i' 'm->y' 'b->ye' 'h->i' 'w->hy' (etc.)

Now as you can see, they are not equally long, so they do not align :(
I'd like to have all the first symbols aligned, all the second symbols aligned, etc.

Comment: Can you please, add to question what you have now and what you want to get. In examples, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is just an issue of how you are displaying the two cell arrays of strings in the command window, you can just [vertically concatenate](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/vertcat.html) the cell arrays and [display](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/disp.html) them like so:

```
>> V1 = {'hi' 'my' 'bye' 'hi' 'why'};            %# Cell array one
>> V2 = {'h->i' 'm->y' 'b->ye' 'h->i' 'w->hy'};  %# Cell array two
>> disp([V1; V2])
    'hi'      'my'      'bye'      'hi'      'why'  
    'h->i'    'm->y'    'b->ye'    'h->i'    'w->hy'
```

Answer (score 0):

`char` converts cell arrays of strings to character matrices, which pads each string in the array to the same length.

```
V1 = {'hi' 'my' 'bye' 'hi' 'why'}
char(V1)
V2 = {'h->i' 'm->y' 'b->ye' 'h->i' 'w->hy'}
char([V1; V2])
```

Comment: thank you! the first solution worked for me as well, but I am really gratful, people here are extremely helpful!